# How to submit different forms with same input

Tags: html

Im trying to implement the "i'm feeling lucky" functionality in a quite simple web. The thing is that at first, without this button, the query was properly done (i mean when doing a normal search). But, when i included the im feeling lucky button, the normal search stopped working and know even when you click on norma search it goes directly to the firs result. im new to HTML and still lost regarding forms. Note that i cant do it using js cause its for an assignment meant to be done only with HTML.

Thanks a lot for your help :D

```html
<a href="image.html">Image</a>
<a href="advanced.html">Advanced</a>

<form action="https://www.google.com/search?">
  <div><input type="text" name="q" id="search"></div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" id="button">
    <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="btnI" value="1">
      <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky" id="button">
    </form>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that you need two buttons with one text field, perhaps a different approach would be useful. Use

`<button type="submit" name="action" value="val1"></button>`

and

`<button type="submit" name="action" value="val2"></button>`

but be careful with this one, since some browsers will upload value from the "value" attribute.

The other method is to use some PHP in your script, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="update_button" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="Delete" />
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['update_button'])) {
    //update button 
} else if (isset($_POST['delete_button'])) {
    //delete button
} else {
    //no button was pressed
}
?>
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest forms

You need two forms:

```html
<a href="image.html">Image</a>
<a href="advanced.html">Advanced</a>

<form action="https://www.google.com/search?">
  <div><input type="text" name="q" id="search"></div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" id="button">
    <input type="hidden" name="btnI" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
<form action="https://www.google.com/search?"><input type="hidden" name="q" value="I'm feeling lucky"><button>I'm feeling lucky</button></form>
```

Comment: Ok i see the nesting problem. Now, the thing is, i want the im feeling lucky button to go directly to google's first result. On the other hand, "google search" button should show you all the results as in when you search something normally on google. For this purpouse, both buttons should use the text written in the text input. Thank you for you answer it was very helpful to understand the nesting problem.

Comment: You cannot easily do that without JS

Answer (score -1):

A few notes:

1. you have a form tag nested inside the other which is wrong.
2. you have two submit button with same id.

Remove these issues and it will work as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I changed what you said. Google search button shows all the results for the google search as intended. Now the thing is that the feeling lucky button doesn't search anything. I want it to also use the content in the text input from the previous form (using only one input text) and take you directly to the first google result.

Answer (score -1):

As I see it, you want to have window inside another window, both of which will have buttons? In that case, don't go form inside form, make it div inside div and in both of them, enter a form, here's and example:

```
<div id="div1">
   <form action="https://www.google.com/search?">
     <input type="text" name="q" id="search">
     <input type="submit" value="Google Search" id="btn1" class="button">
   </form>
   <div id="div2">
     <form action="https://www.google.com/search?">
       <input type="text" name="q2" id="search">
       <input type="submit" value="Google Search" id="btn2" class="button">
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that i want a single text input. This input should be used by both buttons but in different ways depending on the button. Thanks again :D

Comment: I've posted another answer, check it out :D